# If function with multiple inputs that returns text strings with variable

Tags: microsoft-excel

Essentially I have 4 columns of values I'm pulling from.

A: "Old # of Cards"

B: "Old Std Pack Qty"

C: "New # of Cards"

D: "New Std Pack Qty"

In a separate column E, I comment what changes need to be made.

If all values stay the same then I write "Keep Same"

If the A > C "Delete X card(s)" or if A < C "Add X card(s)" where X = A-C or C-A

If B ≠ D "Change Std Pack to Y" where Y = B-D or D-B

Also if A ≠ C and B ≠ D then "Add/Delete X Card(s); Change Std Pack to Y"

I almost had it figured out with a bunch of nested if(and's but I'm struggling with getting that "X" variable between the "Add/Delete" and the "card(s)". Also not sure if it's possible to pluralize the "card" if > 1. I'm sure there may be an easier way that doesn't involve the if formulas but I'm not sure what that would be.

Here is what my table would look like:

[image: Card Changes]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What happens if A=C but B ≠ D?

Comment: Are you asking for how to concatenate a variable with text?  So if X is a formula or cell reference it would be `"ADD " & X & " Card(s)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is in A1 to E7.

Place the following formula in E2 and copy down

```
=IF(AND(A2=C2,B2=D2),"Keep Same",IF(A2<>C2,IF(A2>C2,"Delete ","Add ")&ABS(A2-C2)&" card"&IF(ABS(A2-C2)<>1,"s",""),"")&IF(AND(A2<>C2,B2<>D2),"; ","")&IF(B2<>D2,"Change Std Pack to "&D2,""))
```

Note the following part from the formula above is optional.  It is just taking care of placing the s on the end of card when there is more than 1 card being added or deleted.

```
&IF(ABS(A2-C2)<>1,"s","")
```

[image: POC]

Comment: That worked perfectly! I had a complete brain fart on absolute value... I tried googling "make solution positive" to no avail.. So if I'm looking at this correctly, "&" is used to tie the text strings / formulas together?

Comment: & can tie String and (formula, string, numbers, or cell content ie A1).  It is the short form for the formula CONCATENATE.  Of note is the & does not generate a space so you need to include it at the end/start of your string, or potentially in between like A1&" "&B2.

Comment: BTW the result of any concatenation results in a string.  `1&1=11` The 11 is a string and not a number.